# Splitting strings from a file in java?

Tags: java, filereader

The file's strings:

```
    insert ignominious
    insert elephant
    insert judicious
    insert bastion
    insert fastidious
    insert generous
    insert hilarious
    insert astute
    insert degenerate
    insert courageous
    traverse
    remove judicious
    remove ignominious
```

My code splits the strings when there are two words on the line, but when it goes to "traverse", it gives an OutOfBounds error because it is just one word. I'm not sure if you need to make it to check if theres just one word on that line in order to not split and how to do it.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
String str;

while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] strArr = str.split(" ");
    if(strArr[1]!=null)
        System.out.println(strArr[0] + ", "+strArr[1]);
    else
        System.out.println(strArr[0]);
}
in.close();
```

Comment: check `strArr.length`, don't deference an element you don't know exists.

Answer (score 2):

As @markspace said, you should just check for the length of the array.

```
 while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
     String[] strArr = str.split(" ");
        if(strArr.length > 1)
             System.out.println(strArr[0] + ", "+strArr[1]);
        else
            System.out.println(strArr[0]);
}
```

If the idea is to only print the names like this, you could do:

```
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] strArr = str.split(" ");
    System.out.println(String.join(", ", strArr));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this is one step towards solving a larger problem. It is great that you are starting to solve this problem by implementing code to only read the file and print out the commands that you parse. Breaking a larger problem into smaller ones like this is an important skill for a computer programmer. However, in this case, your simplification ignores a detail about the input: some commands have arguments and some do not.

One solution is to check the command stored in `strArr[0]` before attempting to use `strArr[1]`. This command determines whether or not any additional arguments are expected. For example, if `strArr[0]` is `"insert"`, then you know there will be an argument. However, if it is `"traverse"`, then there should not be any argument and you shouldn't try to access `strArr[1]` because you know it doesn't exist.

Comment: I think checking the length is easier than actuallychecking the contents of the first element to see if there is a second. **I do agree that what he does is otherwise excellent: start simple and expand once it works.**

Comment: @RudyVelthuis It appears that the OP is building a parser. In that regard, checking the command name makes more sense. `if (strArr[0].equals("traverse"))` makes the intent immediately obvious whereas `if (strArr.length == 1)` is more obtuse. Checking the command is also more flexible for multiple commands which take varying numbers of arguments.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis In the end, either approach will solve the OP's immediate problem and they can choose which they prefer. I'm simply offering an alternative to the other answer.

Comment: But `if (strArr.length == 1)` will tell him not to access the second element. Once he knows that, he can start evaluating the first element, IMO. And he might also have to account for empty strings, i.e. if the length is 0. Then he should not attempt to read the command either.

Comment: If the length of the array is 0, then there is a syntax error unless the parser allows for blank lines, in which case checking the length makes sense. On the other hand, if the length is 2 but the first word is "traverse" or if the length is 1 but the first word is "insert", there is a syntax error. Eventually the command in `strArr[0]` must be checked anyway, either to detect malformed commands or to carry out those commands. It makes sense to me to do that up front. In the end, either solution will solve the current problem.